# How to get previous months from current month using moment.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

How do I get 4 month names prior to current month using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Here's what I tried to get the previous month as I wanted it to exclude the current month.

```
const previousMonth = moment()
  .subtract(1, 'month')
  .startOf('month')
  .format('MMMM');
```

How do I loop this to get previous months. Could anyone please help?
I was expecting output to be like this

```
April 2020
March 2020
February 2020
January 2020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for` loop and subtract one month each iteration

```js
const start = moment().startOf('month')
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  console.log(start.subtract(1, 'month').format('MMMM YYYY'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-5oApc/wMda1ntIEK4qoWJ4YItnV4fBHMwywunj8gPqc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```